# How to get the scope from where a function was called?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a javascript expression parser, able to parse an expression and get the declared variables in its body, without executing the function:

```js
function test(expressionFn) {
  var expression = getExpression(expressionFn);
  // get value expression.expressionRight in scope
  // not work -> var valueRigthInScope = expressionFn.prototype.constructor[[[Scopes]]][expression.expressionRight];
  console.log(expressionFn.prototype); // see ".constructor[[[Scopes]]]" in debug tools [F12]
}

function getExpression(expressionFn) {
  var strAfterReturn = expressionFn.toString().split("return")[1].trim();
  let strExpression = strAfterReturn.split(";")[0].split(" ");
  return {
      expressionLeft: strExpression[0],
      operator: strExpression[1],
      expressionRight: strExpression[2]
  };
}

function start(){
 var myValue = "This is value!";
 test(function(x) { return x.prop1 == myValue; });
}

start();
```

```html
<h1>See console</h1>
```

[Example in JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pzjs7ynh/).

But I can not access the scope of the function to get the value of the variable `myValue`, for example.

In the Google Chrome console I managed through the function to get the scope where the variable `myValue` is declared, but I can not access that same scope in javascript.

Follows the image of the Google Chrome console:

[image]

How can I access `[[Scopes]]` in the image?

Comment: You cannot programmatically access scope from within JavaScript. This is impossible by design, and the output you see is strictly available within the debugging tools of the console.

Comment: you can't. you would need to `eval()` the code in the same local scope as your desired var is defined. Also, functions can have multiple returns and nested functions, so your "parser" is very fragile and limited.

Comment: if you want to make myValue accessible from OUTSIDE the function .. use `window.myValue =  'whatever'`

Comment: [This is a XY problem.](http://xyproblem.info) What do you actually want to achieve? Why are you parsing JavaScript functions?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, So the answer to my question is 'no', is it not possible to access the Scope object via javascript? Or alternatively? Just to clarify, what I am trying to implement with this is an analyzer that can get the expression information, similar to the [Lambda Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions). My current implementation state covers much better parse of various function formats and also has a more closed format of supported functions because I use this with Typescript.