# How to display javascript prototype, conscructor, scope inside html element

Tags: javascript, console.log

- I'm trying to create a simulator for `console.log` to use it in my phone to show deferant datatype result, code errors - the code is working fine and display, highlight all datatypes

[image]

- but i want also to display `constcrutor`, `scopes`, `prototypes` like the web console is there's a way to loop throw them and get their data like this image

[image]

Comment: [this](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) link may help you

Comment: See also [Programmatically accessing `[[Scopes]]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52150979/1048572), [What is `[[Scopes]]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45506745/1048572) and [How to get the scope from where a function was called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45313383/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `constructor` property can be gotten by referencing it explicitly, or by iterating over all properties of the object (not just enumerable properties), with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`.

The `[[Prototype]]` property is equivalent to the value returned by `Object.getPrototypeOf`, so you can call that to access the prototype object and iterate through it too, if you want.

Perhaps something like:

```js
const recursiveLogAllProperties = (obj) => {
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(prop => console.log(prop, obj[prop]));
  const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  if (proto === Object.prototype) return;
  console.log('------ Prototype:');
  recursiveLogAllProperties(proto);
}
const arr = [1, 2];
recursiveLogAllProperties(arr);
```

The `[[Scopes]]` internal property is not accessible from JavaScript.