# What is [[Scopes]] in dispatch() of redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, redux, react-redux

I am using redux with react. This makes dispatch available as props in component. So when I `console.log(this.props)` I see following object in log under dispatch key.

```
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[5]
   0:Closure
   1:Closure
   2:Closure (createThunkMiddleware)
   3:Closure
   4:Global
```

Can someone explain what is this ?

Comment: A very strange output ?

Comment: Complete log `dispatch: function (action)
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length:1
name: ""
prototype: Object
__proto__:function ()
[[FunctionLocation]] : index.js?f248:9
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[5]
errorText:undefined }`

Comment: I don't understand the question :-) You don't have dispatch in props ?

Comment: Yes i have .. and this is it. its working fine.. I just want to know what is the meaning of this log.  What is [[Scopes]] and its closure.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`[[Scopes]]` is a private property that Chrome developer tools add and use internally, in C++, [here in the source](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/943651b789f8757fd86f133b606eb7d2a86bcc1b/src/inspector/v8-debugger.cc#L682). It displays the variables that are in the scope of a function, i.e. which variables can be accessed from that function.

For example:

```
function a() {
  var foo = 'foo';
  var obj = {
    bar: function () {
      return foo;
    }
  };
  console.log(obj);
}
a();
```

Here, the function that is attached to property `obj.bar` has variable `foo` in its scope, so when we inspect the `[[Scopes]]` propety of `obj.bar` we see something like

```
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[2]
0: Closure (a)
  foo: "foo"
1: Global
  (all global variables)
```

---

You can manually inspect these properties in the console, which might be helpful for debugging, but you can't access them using JavaScript and you shouldn't care about them in your application code.

See also: [SO - Access function location programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146373/access-function-location-programmatically).