# Get a property listed in the browser's Event Listener tab programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, event-listener

I'm wondering if it is possible to get a HTML element's property listed in the Event Listeners tab?

[image: Event Listeners tab]

The console command

```
getEventListeners(window.document.activeElement)
```

gives the full list.

But is it possible to get the above displayed property `_oRecord` through its "property path"?

A right click in the browser allows me to copy the property path, i.e. [""0""].P._oRecord in my case.

With `getEventListeners()`, I can get the function, while I need to get one of the "[[Scopes]]" properties.

[image: Expanded event listeners object tree]

Comment: `[[Scope]]` is an internal property of the Javascript engine. It's probably only/exclusively exposed by the dev tools UI. It's not meant to be accessible via Javascript itself. To be sure: you want to access that property programmatically, via a script in the console; inspection via the panel is not sufficient for you? Please clarify that, your text is a bit ambiguous. [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): why so you want to access that property via the console, what do you want to achieve/solve?

Comment: The page I need to analyse, displays a big array of lines, and each line opens a textarea. I'm trying to make the link between the textarea which is open when the user clicks in the line, and the line itself.

Comment: I hope you want to make the "link" (connection) between both just for debugging not for production. Note that `getEventListeners()` is only a Chrome developer tools function, not available to the page's code and possibly not available to other browser tools at all. If debugging: consider this tip: attach the event listener to the common parent element and examine `target` to know the actual element in the event object to spare you managing dozens of event listeners (search this site or google for "event delegation").

Answer (score 0):

`[[Scopes]]` is an [internal property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45508961/1078886) of the Javascript engine. It's only exposed to the developer tools.

**You can't access this property programmatically via Javascript.**

Though what you could do is, manually storing the object as global variable and inspect it programmatically:

[image: Store as variable]

(Right-click on `[[Scopes]]`)

Say it has been stored as `temp1`, then this would allow you to further inspect the scope information programmatically:

```
Object.values(temp1).map((s) => s.object)
```

Comment: Sorry too hear that. Thanks anyway for the the try.

Comment: There might be a Chrome extension giving you access to this information. You might even be able to access these properties via Chrome extensions. Though I'm not sure it's possible. It's just a thought.